# create column in for each different value in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Let us say that I have a table structured like this(using SQL server):

```
empID INT
payment INT
```

Now, each employee only gets paid either 50.00 or 100.00. There are two employees earning 50.00 and three earning 100.00.

How would I do a select statement so that the result set was like this:

```
50.00   100
-----   -----
2       3
```

Where 50.00 and 100.00 are the column headers, and the number below are the actual values. I know that I can do

```
SELECT payment, COUNT(*)
FROM Student
GROUP BY payment
```

But that returns the payment in its own column. I want each different payment value in its own column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

```
select sum(case when payment = 50.00 then 1 else 0 end) as num050,
       sum(case when payment = 100.00 then 1 else 0 end) as num100
```

But, with floating point numbers, you should never do equal comparisons.  It is better to do something like:

```
sum(case when abs(payment - 50) < 0.001 then 1 else 0 end)
```

or something like that.

Comment: And if you absolutely want column headers of `50` and `100`, just change `as num050` to `as [50.00]`.  The brackets will allow you to use all numbers as a column header.

Comment: @user1319343, if this is the solution, please mark it as the correct answer, for future reference. Thank you.